# Set id for many-to-one field without entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

The are a lot of cases where I don't want to load the full entity and I can use lazy loading for it. But in case if I want to **set** id of such an entity how can I do it without this entity itself?

```
public class UserTournament
{
    public User Owner {get; set; }
    ...    
}
```

I have only User.Id here but not the entire User. E.g. I need to save a new UserTournament for User#5. Should I break ORM concepts and use OwnerId int property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ISession.Load<T>(id)`, it will create a proxy with the ID set so that the relationship can be saved. See also http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id